# Angular material mat menu styling issue

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have two components that using mat menu. I just want to add some extra styling for one mat menu in one component. I have used this css inside the component css

```
::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel
  {
      position: fixed !important;
      right : 2%;
  }
```

Now the issue is the css is applying to the other component mat menu also.
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add your panel styling to your global style sheet:

```
.fixed-menu-panel
{
    position: fixed !important;
    right : 2%;
}
```

Add the panel style to the mat-menu:

```
<mat-menu class="fixed-menu-panel">
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bheaf?file=index.html

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that the menu is rendered in an overlay container attached to the parent document and not the button itself... with this in mind, you will need to think about how to grab a reference to that `mat-menu-panel` and append a class to it to make it unique on menu open.

For example, you could do something like the following to accomplish this.

Create a component method that will receive the `templateRef` as an argument. It will get the `mat-menu-panel` using `Renderer2` and append a class to it of `styled`

```
  styleMenu(el) {
    const menuPanel = this.ren.parentNode(this.ren.parentNode(el.items.first['_elementRef'].nativeElement));

    this.ren.addClass(menuPanel, 'styled')
  }
```

Then in your view, use the `(menuOpened)` event emitter to call the `styleMenu` method when the menu opens, and pass the `#styledMenu` templateRef as an argument.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="styledMenu" (menuOpened)="styleMenu(styledMenu)">styled</button>
<mat-menu #styledMenu="matMenu">
```

Then your CSS will look like this

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel.styled 
  {
      position: fixed !important;
      right : 2%;
  }
```

This is one approach, you could also roll all of this into a `directive` and then just apply the directive `selector` where you need it.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5nixtl?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.ts